# Computer randomly goes into sleep mode

Tags: sleep

For a while I have had no problems with my Asus laptop running Windows 7. It is a decent computer and I need it to run almost 24/7. I restart it every few days but it does continuously run. However, recently my computer has randomly been going into sleep mode. This from the best of my knowledge, has been after I have not been using the computer for a while.

Before people suggest the more obvious solutions, I have checked all power settings for my laptop. They all say never/always on.

Comment: Check the event log under: Windows Logs -> System and check for events from the source "Kernel-Power". Entering sleep mode should be noted there with a Sleep Reason. What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oftentimes the cause of this sort of random hibernation/shutdown is overheating. Most computers are set to hibernate if the internal temperature reaches a certain level. A friend of mine has an Asus laptop, and it tends to run hot. [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) is a very popular piece of software which can be used to check the temperature being reported by your computer's internal sensors. You should be able to find a datasheet for your CPU, which will tell you the heat tolerances, and whether it is in fact the heat that is causing it to hibernate.

Answer (score 4):

LOL! I found an other cause:

I followed the instructions from Oliver Salzburg because my computer my computer fall asleep. In the Log it said: Sleep Reason: lid close... wich was not the reason because it happend while I was working on the laptop.

Then I realized the reason: I'm wearing a bracelet with a magnetic clasp... Lid close is registered via a magnet in the lid ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You say power settings were checked. Did you check settings under Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings and then go to Advanced settings and go through and expand every + section? Sometimes there's some missed there. Also check Hibernation if you haven't thought of it already.

Just covering some bases for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you aren't wearing a magnetic bracelet or watchband of any kind while typing. If the magnet hits the corner of your computer while typing, it will put your computer to sleep.  I have a blaze watchband that has a magnet, and it was putting my computer to sleep randomly. I thought my computer was having hardware issues.  I was the one having hardware issues.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I noticed my power button was somewhat overused. Just pull it up a bit, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was putting my phone on the corner of the laptop and it randomly entered sleep mode. I read your answers and figured it out after. Try going to Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings and then click "Change advanced power settings", then in that window search for "Power buttons and lid", and then click "lid close action" and set it to "do nothing". Hope it solves the issue for you as it did for me.